# some issues with web scraping imd website

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping

So I was scraping this Indian weather website

```
http://202.54.31.7/citywx/localwx.php
```

So from the left pane you can see all the Indian states, and if you hover over them you can select the cities/districts. So I chose `Delhi->safdarjung` from left pane and saved this page locally as:-

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib, urllib2

imd_ind = urllib2.urlopen('http://202.54.31.7/citywx/localwx.php')
delhi_info = imd_ind.read()
open('delhi_info.html', 'w').write(delhi_info)
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('delhi_info.html'))
soup.prettify
```

print only this much :-

```
<bound method BeautifulSoup.prettify of <html><head><title>Local Weather Forecast</title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<meta content="MSHTML 5.00.2920.0" name="GENERATOR" /></head>
<frameset border="0" cols="330,611*" frameborder="NO" framespacing="0" rows="*"><frame name="menuFrame" noresize="noResize" src="menu.php" /><frame name="mainframe" src="http://202.54.31.7/citywx/city_weather1.php?id=42182" /></frameset></html>
>
```

Whereas if I inspect the locally saved page "delhi_info.html" in chrome, I can see hell lot of information date, temperature, cloudy etc etc (i.e. lots of ,  's ) , but why cant I see them via any of BeautifulSoup methods.
Please help

Comment: you are opening the file for reading before closing it for writing, so some contents is most likely still being buffered and has not been written to disk yet. try: `with open('delhi_info.html','w') as f: f.write(delhi_info)` instead.

Comment: Thanks isedev, so what should I do to correct it. Pls help !!.

Comment: Nope, even if you print out the content `delhi_info` you will get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have frame element in the HTML. 
You have this code in your saved HTML file:

```
src="http://202.54.31.7/citywx/city_weather1.php?id=42182"
```

BeautifulSoup can't scrap this frame, so you need to extract this URL, open it and then scrap the data.